# how to sync app local storage to database?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, mongodb, cordova

I'm curious about how Trello does their data with their local and server storage.

I'd like to know how can I make this possible on the app that I'm developing. It's just a mobile point of sale and likes to have an offline capability in which I store the data locally.

I'm using Cordova for Android and iOS. Nodejs and MongoDB for my server and database.

Answer (score 1):

The way they do this is likely by using localStorage in the browser which you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). If not, there are other offline database techniques for web apps, documented in detail by google [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa#current_and_future_offline_storage_work). According to the [Cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html#localstorage), this is also supported in cordova apps.

As a rough sketch, in order to make your app work offline, you should utilize localStorage, or some other offline DB to store things and also try to send the data to the server to sync it up there. If it doesn't work, mark the data as not being synced. Then, every subsequent time you try and hit the server, dont just sync up the most recent change, but also sync up all other changes that have not yet been sent to the server.

It is important to know that in any reasonably complex application, utilizing offline storage is quite complex because of the challenges involved with syncing the data with the server and trying to create a consistent DB. Also, localStorage can only be accessed synchronously and so the website will freeze up (even if for a moment for most queries) while trying to retrieve the data.

Good luck!